# Loop through rows of input matrices with vectorize

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a `4x2` and a `2x2` matrices. I would like to loop each combination of rows (vectors of dimension 2) through a function `foo` using `vectorize`.

Here are the matrices:

```
X = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4,0]])
Y = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 0]])
```

Here's how I'm trying to run it:

```
def foo(x, y):
    print("inputs:", x, y)
    return x[0] * y[0]

bar = np.vectorize(foo, signature="???")
output = bar(X, Y)
print(output)
```

I'm looking for the following output. `bar` would return a `4x2` matrice:

```
inputs: [1,0] [1,0]
inputs: [1,0] [2,0]
inputs: [2,0] [1,0]
inputs: [2,0] [2,0]
inputs: [3,0] [1,0]
inputs: [3,0] [2,0]
inputs: [4,0] [1,0]
inputs: [4,0] [2,0]
[[1,2], [2,4], [3,6], [4,8]]
```

I've tried various combinations of `signature`, but I'm just not grokking how to use it given the output I'm looking for.

NB: I am aware vectorize just uses Python `for` loops under the hood and offers no performance benefit. I just want to understand how to use it.

Comment: You can use np.tensordot(X[:,0], Y[:,0], axes=0)

Comment: @Bas what `foo()` is doing here is just an example. I'm trying to understand how to use `vectorize` to loop through each combination of rows without having to write a nested loop myself.

Comment: Honestly, I find `output = [[bar(x,y) for y in Y] for x in X]` much more readable than `bar = np.vectorize(foo, signature="???");output = bar(X, Y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic use of `vectorize` broadcasts the inputs against each other, and passes scalar tuples to your function. A (4,2) can't broadcast with a (2,2). signature is an addition that should make it possible to pass "rows" of your arrays. It's even slower, and I haven't see it used much (or recommended it).

```
In [536]: bar = np.vectorize(foo, signature="(n),(n)->()")

In [533]: bar(X,Y[0,:])
inputs: [1 0] [1 0]
inputs: [2 0] [1 0]
inputs: [3 0] [1 0]
inputs: [4 0] [1 0]
Out[533]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [537]: bar(X[:,None],Y[None])
inputs: [1 0] [1 0]
inputs: [1 0] [2 0]
inputs: [2 0] [1 0]
inputs: [2 0] [2 0]
inputs: [3 0] [1 0]
inputs: [3 0] [2 0]
inputs: [4 0] [1 0]
inputs: [4 0] [2 0]
Out[537]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 6],
       [4, 8]])
```

So this gives `bar` a (4,1,2) and (1,2,2); which broadcast as (4,2,2).  Or with this signature it's broadcasting a (4,1) with 1,2) => (4,2).  It's the signature that determines how the last dimensions match.

It may in some cases be convenient, but I wouldn't recommend devoting too much time to understanding `vectorize`.